Le Sage's Quantum Gravity Theory and the 5th force of Nature?
Le Sage's theory of gravitation when you first learn about it is surprisingly a 16th century theory of quantum gravity, a precursor to the modern term referring to this field of research which by many is regarded as the most hot research topic today. Therefore, Le Sage could be regarded as one of the fathers of quantum gravity.
It describes as empty space or vacuum being actually full of unmeasurable tiny particles and gravity is a push-pressure force caused by these quanta of gravity to normal matter.
In Le Sage's theory, everything in the universe becomes local and causally-connected. There are no nonlocal effects.
Imagine normal fermionic matter is submerged inside sand (vacuum) where each sand grain is one of these Le Sage's vacuum quanta.
I find Le Sage's theory and model fascinating even today and like to ask you what are the incurable shortcomings and failures of this theory?
And secondly, does Le Sage's quanta of gravity, vacuum and fabric of spacetime itself actually describe what we could call the extra dimensions Planck-sized Kaluza-Klein manifold yet undiscovered 5th force of nature?

ha! what a fun read. Of course Le Sage did not know about atomic nuclei or quantum mechanics but concluding that matter is mostly empty space in order to make GRAVITY work, is a very interesting conclusion! People were as creative back then as they are today

immediately fails due to thermal constraints

@naturallyInconsistent are you saying that Le Sage's particle background would create too extreme of a thermal bath? It's not clear what you mean by "fails due to thermal constraints".

Did you not read the Wikipedia link that you cited? It explains in lots of details the many ways this theory fails

Re: "what are the incurable shortcomings and failures if this theory?"
Probably the biggest shortcoming is we have NO evidence of these particles that cause pressure on objects.
It's not clear how you would devise an experiment to look for these particles. Ideally one would expect to detect them in a way not dissimilar to how Brownian motion revealed the presence of atoms. But perhaps the distance scales we should find this brownian motion to occur at are far beyond our experimental abilities.
Re: "does Le Sage's quanta of gravity and the quanta of vacuum but also quanta of the fabric of spacetime itself actually describe what we could call the extra dimensions Planck sized Kaluza-klein manifold yet undiscovered 5th force of nature?"
This is not a coherent sentence. But If I had to guess what you are asking I would say certainly not! The article on Wikipedia just talks about small particles bumping into all objects that have mass (or stress-energy tensor now that we have Einstein's view?). I don't see any mention of extra dimensions here. If you want to make up a philosophical idea that Le Sage's corpuscles live in extra dimensions I suppose you could but in this space why not just assume there's 100-dimensional turtles operating a simulation that makes the universe run? My point is, that this is not a productive line of thought without having some kind of reason to explore it.
